# Is the minimum a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

Let's consider a continuous function
$$ f:\mathbb{R}\times [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$$
Such that $g(y)=\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is well defined for every $y\in[a,b]$.

Is it true that $g(y)$ is continuous on [a,b]?

I believe this statement to be true, but I don't know how to prove it. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Write definition for 2 variable and consider $min$ there.

Comment: Could you explain that, please

Comment: I think you will  need uniform continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R} \times[a, b] $. Just continuity does not seem to be enough.

Comment: How would you follow in that case?

Comment: Apply the definition of continuity as well as that of uniform continuity. For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x, y) - f(x, y+h) |<\epsilon$ for all $x$, some fixed $y$ and all $h$ with $|h|<\delta$. Proceed further based on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No in general. Counterexample:

$$f : \mathbb R\times [0,1] \to \mathbb R,\ \ \ f(x, y) = \max\left\{\frac{1}{1+(yx)^2},\frac12\right\}. $$

In this example,

$$ g(y) = \begin{cases} 1/2 &\text{if } y>0, \\ 1 & \text{if } y=0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Spot on. If there's still any confusion, a simple graph drawing these two lines would definitely clear any doubts